# variables, in a class or in a method which is better?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, coding-style

just wondering which one of these would be the best to practice?

code 1:

```
public void push<T>(T pushthis)
{
    pusher pusher = new pusher();
    pusher.push(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(pushthis));
}
```

code 2:

```
public void push<T>(T pushthis)
{
    pusher pusher = new pusher();
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    pusher.push(serializer.Serialize(pushthis));
}
```

code 3:

```
public class pusher()
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    public void push<T>(T pushthis)
    {
       pusher pusher = new pusher();                
       pusher.push(serializer.Serialize(pushthis));
    }
}
```

I want to know if better make a variable for serializer, and if yes where to put it, inside the method or inside the class
And i will be using the push method many times, with just an instance of the class pusher.

And if possible, can you site some references for me to study for code optimization

Comment: If the performance of 2 and 3 is similar enough, I would prefer 2 because it explicitly scopes the variable `pusher`. This makes the code much more readable to somebody who might not know that pusher's state isn't important after the function ends.

Comment: Also, unless you need to optimize, don't! (Only optimize code if it is in a critical path or is run many thousands of times etc etc). http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: thanks @WayneUroda for the site and concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and the second ways of coding the method are identical. The local variable is defined and used immediately; there are no other places where `serializer` is used.

The third way of coding reuses `serializer` across multiple invocations of `pusher`. It does not call the constructor of `JavaScriptSerializer` multiple times, and therefore may be more efficient.

You could possibly share `JavaScriptSerializer` among all instances of class `pusher` by making the `serializer` variable `static`. Unless you change configuration dynamically, for example by calling `RegisterConverters`, you may be able to reduce the number of invocations of the constructor further.

Comment: it is only now that i really understand where that static thing could be useful thanks, about the code 1 and code 2, im just thinking instead of storing it to a variable, i will just use it directly, even to the slightest difference which one is better, by performance, neglecting readability. Thanks

Comment: @sclang If the variable is used only in one place, the compiler is free to optimize it out, producing the same MSIL for both codes 1 and 2.

Comment: @sclang Methods that do not use instance variables can be made `static`. Methods that use only `static` variables can be made `static` too.

Comment: Sorry i deleted the question, i thought about that it will remain as 1, but your second statement surprised me again, your'e really good, about the static int, where should it be declared, in a method or class? ,.. can you also site a scenario where static methods would be beneficial for performance? Sorry, if i have too many questions.

Comment: @sclang In C# `static` can be declared only in a class, not in a function. Static methods are not used for performance benefits, but for organizing the code. If a method is not using instance variables, make it `static`.

Comment: "If a method is not using instance variables, make it static." Why should i not make a method static if it is using instance variables? What are the possible effects? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sclang If a static method attempts to use instance variables, it would not compile.

Comment: hi dasblinkenlight,.. does this static thing about class variables, works exactly the same if i made a static class,.. i made a static class to have global variables,.. so even i make 2 instance of a class,.. it will still access the static class which have global variables? meaning they will access the same class therefore same variables? thanks.

Comment: @sclang If you make a static class, the compiler will check that all its methods and variables are static, and give you an error if any of its members is non-static or if you try instantiating a static class. Other than that, a static class is the same as a non-static one: their static variables behave exactly the same - they are shared among all instances.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is much difference in code 1 and code 2.  If you are using the push method multiple times then make it a class level variable rather than local /method level variable

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is to measure performance.

I really doubt you'll see much difference, if any. When you create an object in a method it will go out of scope at the end of the method and be efficiently GC'd.

If you declare the JavaScriptSerializer as a field on the class you need to make sure that it is thread-safe if you'll be calling it concurrently.